# TSP / CPP variant - subtour constraint

Tags: traveling-salesman, integer-programming

I'm developing an optimization problem that is a variant on Traveling Salesman.  In this case, you don't have to visit all the cities, there's a required start and end point, there's a min and max bound on the tour length, you can traverse each arc multiple times if you want, and you have a nonlinear objective function that is associated with the arcs traversed (and number of times you traverse each arc).  Decision variables are integers, how many times you traverse each arc.

I've developed a nonlinear integer program in Pyomo and am getting results from the NEOS server.  However I didn't put in subtour constraints and my results are two disconnected subtours.

I can find integer programming formulations of TSP that say how to formulate subtour constraints, but this is a little different from the standard TSP and I'm trying to figure out how to start.  Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: problem formulation

50 arcs , not exhaustive pairs between nodes. 50 Decision variables N_ab are integer >=0, corresponds to how many times you traverse from a to b. There is a length and profit associated with each N_ab . There are two constraints that the sum of length_ab * N_ab for all ab are between a min and max distance. I have a constraint that the sum of N_ab into each node is equal to the sum N_ab out of the node you can either not visit a node at all, or visit it multiple times. Objective function is nonlinear and related to the interaction between pairs of arcs (not relevant for subtour).

Subtours: looking at math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/methods/opt/subtour.htm , the formulation isn't applicable since I am not required to visit all cities, and may not be able to. So for example, let's say I have 20 nodes and 50 arcs (all arcs length 10). Distance constraints are for a tour of exactly length 30, which means I can visit at most three nodes (start at A -> B -> C ->A = length 30). So I will not visit the other nodes at all. TSP subtour elimination would require that I have edges from node subgroup ABC to subgroup of nonvisited nodes - which isn't needed for my problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that is adapted from the prize-collecting TSP (e.g., [this paper](https://math.mit.edu/~goemans/PAPERS/BienstockGSW-1993-PrizeCollecting.pdf)). Let `V` be the set of all nodes. I am assuming `V` includes a *depot* node, call it node 1, that must be on the tour. (If not, you can probably add a dummy node that serves this role.)

Let `x[i]` be a decision variable that equals 1 if we visit node `i` at least once, and 0 otherwise. (You might already have such a decision variable in your model.) 
Add these constraints, which define `x[i]`:

```
x[i] <= sum {j in V} N[i,j]    for all i in V
M * x[i] >= N[i,j]             for all i, j in V
```

In other words: `x[i]` cannot equal 1 if there are no edges coming out of node `i`, and `x[i]` must equal 1 if there are any edges coming out of node `i`.
(Here, `N[i,j]` is 1 if we go from `i` to `j`, and `M` is a sufficiently large number, perhaps equal to the maximum number of times you can traverse one edge.)

Here is the subtour-elimination constraint, defined for all subsets `S` of `V` such that `S` includes node 1, and for all nodes `i` in `V \ S`:

```
sum {j in S} (N[i,j] + N[j,i]) >= 2 * x[i]
```

In other words, if we visit node `i`, which is not in `S`, then there must be at least two edges into or out of `S`. (A subtour would violate this constraint for `S` equal to the nodes that are on the subtour that contains 1.)

We also need a constraint requiring node 1 to be on the tour:

```
x[1] = 1
```

I might be playing a little fast and loose with the directional indices, i.e., I'm not sure if your model sets `N[i,j] = N[j,i]` or something like that, but hopefully the idea is clear enough and you can modify my approach as necessary.